# Type casting to template return type

Tags: types, casting

Please consider the code below. Three questions:

1) what happens if I perform an operation with `T` that is not defined on `T`

Regarding the obvious problematic `int` as return of my function template:

2) does `g++` always try at the end, after having gotten to the end of and instance of the template function `T` to convert `T`, in this case `double`, to `int` ?

3) What happens if `T` is a class for which there is no obvious type casting (like here, from `double` to `int`) ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int test(T b, T c) {
   return c+b;
} 


int main(int argc, char** argv ) {
    std::cout << test(0.43,-0.23);
}
```

Comment: In 2), are you asking if the compiler will implicitly cast the return type?

Comment: @SamusArin `test` computes `something` internally, that is made up out of `T`, but `something` can't be returned, only `int` can. So I'm asking,  whether the compiler will silently cast `something` to `int` when returning. Thus I assume "yes" would be the answer to your question.Unfortunately I didn't get your explanation for 2).  But thanks for the answer - unfortunately I can't upvote yet, I need 15 rep for that, but I will return to it, once I have 15 rep.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/  `cout` is actually an instance of `ostream`, which defines many overloads for the `<<` operator, including one for `doubles` (`ostream& operator<< (double val);`).  If the type being returned by test, `something` isn't a direct match to one of the overloads, then the compiler should cast it to the most appropriate type (ie, if `something` is non-primitive, then it should print it's memory address using the `unsigned int` variation of the << overload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) what happens if I perform an operation with T that is not defined
>   on T

If `T` is either a primitive type for which there is no operation defined, or  non-primitive with no overloaded operator, then you'll get a compile time error.

> 2) does g++ always try at the end, after having gotten to the end of
>   an instance of the template function T to convert T, in this case
>   double, to int ?

If you try to cast to `int` before printing to `cout`, like

```
cout << (int) test(0.43,-0.23)
```

the compiler will only cast after the function is called, so that the args `b` and `c` will be treated as, and operated on as, `doubles` within `test()`.

> 3) What happens if T is a class for which there is no obvious type
>   casting (like here, from double to  int) ?

Primitives can only be cast to other, allowable primitives, and non-primitives can only be cast to base-types. For primitive types, you'll get a compile-time error, and for non-primitives you'll either get a compile or run-time error depending on when T is determined (weather it's type binding is early or late (like in a polymorphic call for instance)).

---

**UPDATE**

`cout` is an instance of [**`ostream`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), which defines many overloads for the `<<` operator (these are just the arithmetic overloads):

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (long long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
```

If the type being returned by test, `something`, isn't a direct match to one of the overloads, then the compiler should cast it to the most appropriate type (ie, if `something` is non-primitive, then it should print it's memory address using the `unsigned int` variation of the << overload) - I need to verify this for you, going to have to bust out my ubuntu laptop.